# loading a serialized variable in perl

Tags: perl, serialization, deserialization

I have a file, where I keep stored a serialized perl hash. In my current script, I load the values like this:

```
my $arrayref = retrieve("mySerializedFile");
my $a = $arrayref->[0];
my $b = $arrayref->[1];
my $c = $arrayref->[2];
```

My problem is that the file is about a 1GB so it takes about ten secs to load, and then a second more to perform some operations. I would like to reduce the `retrieve` time.

Is there any way of having this info loaded before the script execution? I mean, mySerialiedFile is not suposed to be changed in a long time, so if I could have it loaded always on the system would be nice, and would improve my execution time from 11secs to 1.

Comment: Have you considered breaking the file up and storing it in a database?

Comment: Sure you can keep it loaded in memory... Don't exit the process! When a process exits, its memory vanishes along with it, so that's the only way to keep it in memory. /// But that means you'd have to give your program an interface that can be queries to obtain desired information from the dump when needed. We're talking about a lot of where here. /// But you know what? You could avoid all that by placing the data in a format that can be queried in the first place! Placing the data in a database is one way you could do that.

Comment: And with the "file-based relational database engine" [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) you don't need an administered client-server system. Perl's interface is [DBD::SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-SQLite/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm), and comes with all that is needed.

Comment: For simple data structures, I just use `redis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions in the comments, I used a db engine, which improved A LOT the execution time, which is about 5secs now.